# my calculator doesnot multiply or divide numbers

Tags: java, calculator

I made a calculator which does not multiply or divide numbers 
and give me an exception :

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "*7"

the plus and minus don't have any problem

```
class ActionListeners implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object o = e.getSource();
        int n1 = 0;
        int n2 = 0;
        int indexno = 0;
        if (o == result) {

            String s = t1.getText();

            String s3 = "";
            String s4 = "";
            for (int b1 = 0; b1 < s.length(); ++b1) {
                if (s.charAt(b1) == '+') {
                    indexno = s.indexOf('+');
                    s3 = s.substring(0, indexno);
                    s4 = s.substring(indexno);
                    n1 = Integer.parseInt(s3);
                    n2 = Integer.parseInt(s4);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, n1 + n2);
                }
                if (s.charAt(b1) == '-') {
                    indexno = s.indexOf('-');
                    s3 = s.substring(0, indexno);
                    s4 = s.substring(indexno);
                    n1 = Integer.parseInt(s3);
                    n2 = Integer.parseInt(s4);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, n1 + n2);
                }
                if (s.charAt(b1) == '*') {
                    indexno = s.indexOf('*');
                    s3 = s.substring(0, s.indexOf('*'));
                    s4 = s.substring(indexno);
                    n1 = Integer.parseInt(s3);
                    n2 = Integer.parseInt(s4);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, n1 * n2);
                }
                if (s.charAt(b1) == '/') {
                    indexno = s.indexOf('/');
                    s3 = s.substring(0, s.indexOf('/'));
                    s4 = s.substring(indexno);
                    n1 = Integer.parseInt(s3);
                    n2 = Integer.parseInt(s4);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, n1 / n2);
                }
                if (s.charAt(b1) == '/' && n2 == 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error : cant divide by zero");
                }

            }

            t1.setText("");
        }
```

Comment: Your answer is in the error. `*7` cannot be parsed to an integer, are you grabbing the right things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason `-` works is because of `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, n1 + n2);`... note that you are parsing unary negative values in `n2` and then adding two values; if you did `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, n1 - n2);` you would see your off by one error in subtraction too. You want `s4 = s.substring(indexno + 1);` in each of your `if`(s).

Comment: but why it works in the plus when i make it either (index + 1);

Comment: or (index); without one

Comment: Unary positive. `+1` and `-1` are valid numbers... Your current code would make `1+1` into `1 + +1` (which is still two). Hope that helps.